# Trying to send post request from ejs file with some data to express server but req.body is returning undefined

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, ejs

I am using jquery ajax to send post request to my server along with some data that will be included in my database. The post object is defined in the script of my ejs file.

```
<script>
        const button = document.getElementById('started');

        button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            var post = {};

            if (button.innerHTML === "Start Task") {
                button.innerHTML = "End Task";
                localStorage.startTime = new Date();
            }

            else if (button.innerHTML === "End Task") {
                button.innerHTML = "Submit";
                localStorage.endTime = new Date();
            }

            else if (button.textContent === "Submit") {
                post.title = $('#title').val();
                post.desc = $('#desc').val();
                post.startTime = Date.parse(localStorage.startTime);
                post.endTime = Date.parse(localStorage.endTime);

                console.log(post); //Here, the post object is defined

                $.ajax({ url: '/home', type: 'POST', data: post })
                    .then(res => console.log("successfully posted"))
                    .catch(err => console.log("error", err));
            }
        });
</script>
```

This is my route that handles the post request

```
app.post("/home", (req, res) => {
    Posts.create(req.body.post, (err, done) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error occured while posting to home", err);
            res.redirect("/home");
        } else {
            console.log("Task Added", req.body.post, done);
            res.redirect("/home");
        }
    })
});
```

Here, req.body.post is undefined for some reason. Also, I have bodyparser set up so that is not the issue. Is there something wrong with my ajax request?

Comment: In Ajax request, you are passing data property and on the server side your are reading the post property. Try console.log(req.body.data) to log what you get from request.

Comment: @AzharZafar I did that and it logged undefined.

Comment: can you console.log(req.body) and what it gives you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can just access the data by using `req.body`. but you if want to have `.post` property, change your ajax data parameter to something like this:

```
$.ajax({ url: '/home', type: 'POST', data: {post:post} })
```